# Disabling button through props cancels its onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TL;DR: go to the [react code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-button-cancels-scroll-270hz?file=/src/App.js) and try clicking either buttons a few times. The *Buggy* one doesn't reach the end of the slideshow.

---

I am making a horizontally scrollable slideshow.

[image: screencast of horizontal slideshow prototype]

It is made of a **container** with `overflow: auto` that contains a **track** that overflows it horizontally. Each **slide** is a child of the **track** and is as wide as the viewport. The **container** has an index state representing which **slide** is in view:

```
const slides = [/* some array of json data */]
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
const track = useRef(null)
const container = useRef(null)

return (
  <div ref={container} onScroll={onScroll}>
    <div ref={track}>
      {slides.map(() => (
        <div></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

To keep track of which slide is in view, there is an `onScroll` function:

```
const onScroll = () => {
  const newIndex = // math to get index from DOM
  if (index !== newIndex)
    setIndex(newIndex)
}
```

There is also an `onClick` function that allows the user to automatically *scroll* to the next **slide**:

```
const onClick = () => {
  track.current.children[index + 1].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
}
```

This `onClick` is passed to a **button** component:

```
const BuggyButton = ({ disabled, onClick }) => (
  <button type="button" disabled={disabled} onClick={onClick}>
    click me
  </button>
)
```

When the user reaches the last **slide**, the button gets disabled:

```
<BuggyButton onClick={onClick} disabled={index === slides.length - 1} />
```

**THE PROBLEM:** as soon as the `<BuggyButton/>` gets disabled, the `scrollIntoView` stops (prematurely). **Why is that?**

Here's a the issue fully reproduced and simplified in a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-button-cancels-scroll-270hz?file=/src/App.js

And here's as close as I could get to reproducing the issue in vanilla JS: https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-button-cancels-scroll-vanilla-018mb

---

If you are simply looking for a solution (and not to understand what is happening, there is a `<ProperButton/>` component in the code sandbox that works perfectly fine. With this question I'm trying to understand *what react does under the hood*  that causes the browser to interrupt the scroll and yet maintain its position and not reset it to zero.

Comment: just place BuggyButton inside App

Comment: @ludwiguer I'm looking to understand *why* this is an issue, and less *how* to fix it. Also, in a real codebase, I will have a more complex button component that I can't just declare inside the `render` of another component.

Comment: @ludwiguer however, it is interesting that it works when declared within App and not outside. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In summary, the scroll stops because the state changes and the component re-renders

```
if (index !== newIndex) {
  setIndex(newIndex);
}
```

This has to do with how React handles the reconciliation when the component is inside a closure and when it is not, that's why it behaves differently when you put the button inside the app function and outside.

You can read more about this here

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: but the scroll is on a sibling of the button, not the button itself... How can the button re-rendering have side effects on its sibling?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, when the state changes, react rerenders and then does the reconciliation phase on all of the components whose state and/or props changed. If at the end of this phase, the virtual dom hasn't changed (`ProperButton`) it stops there. If on the other hand the expected DOM output is different (`BuggyButton`), then react removes the appropriate DOM nodes and replaces them with new ones. This is as far as I understand it, and then I have to leap to "this is why the scroll stops".

Comment: What I don't understand is why it makes the scroll stop since the only DOM node that needs to be replaced (the way I understand it) is a <button> that is outside of the scrollable element. And if it replaces a parent then why does the scroll simply stops in place and isn't reset to zero all the way to the left?